# Fix puppy chewing damage on corner of veneer cabinets

Tags: cabinets, damage, veneer

Our puppy chewed on each corner of our IKEA veneer cabinets.  She chewed past to veneer to pressboard.

I would say it is light to medium damage.  The corners are still there.  She basically scraped the veneer off.

Is there a way to repair them without replacing them?

Comment: How about a few pictures so we can see what you see.

Comment: Boy, you have it  nice. We had a dog that ate my wife's shoes, potted plants, and chair legs. He ate so much of the chair legs that we had to replace the chairs and finaly the DOG.

Comment: Thankfully it’s a small dog!

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to make “invisible” joints to the surface.

So, what about adding brass corners to all corners to cover the damage.

As a bonus, they may dissuade the puppy as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Corner protector?**

[image: corner protector]

https://www.vintagehardware.com/proddetail.php?prod=27256&optn0x0y0=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6Or_BRC_ARIsAPzuer_H6EMRmJ6MCdaAm1r5Qqtxv2skJ4s32_sqBtyClLZLeCELK8HWGKoaAoQjEALw_wcB

Something like this will cover the damage and prevent new.  You can get them at any hardware store.  I see Ikea makes some too.